# TortoiseSVN working copy folder with conflicts but file list is empty

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Context : Windows 7 + TortoiseSVN + Visual Studio 2010 + VisualSVN

In the windows explorer , I can see one of my folder with the little red circle (like there is a conflict).

So I do:

```
Righ click on the folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Resolved
```

and then a window titled "resolve" appears telling me "file list is empty"

So I click "Ok" and my folder is still has the red circle,

When I  try "Clean Up", my folder is marked as ok (green circle), but if I go to the parent directory and come back, the red circle reappears.

Maybe I didn't understand well how svn is working, but it's really strange.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little red circle doesn't mean conflict, it means that there's a modification.
Use the check-for-modifications dialog to see what exactly is modified.

Comment: if it's not for conflict, why is there the context menu "resolved ..."

Comment: indeed it's not a conflict (http://tortoisesvn.net/node/138), but still why is there the menu "resolved..." (and in visualsvn, red is for conflicts and yellow for modifications ^^)

Comment: Probably because they didn't bother making the menu check whether anything needs to be resolved.

Comment: The menu is shown for folders so that you can mark all entries below a folder as resolved.

Comment: @remibourgarel, I think that is because the option "Resolve.." is a standard entry of the SVN context menu, it's will always come up, even if the menu is opened for an  unmodified file/folder with a green check-mark on it.

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan has indicated earlier, a red circle overlay with an exclamation mark on it means that either you -or perhaps a running tool- have accessed a file under that folder and edited it.

So now this folder has a local difference than what you last got from the central repository on your latest update (but only against your **last update** and not against the repository itself at its most current state).

An overlay for a conflict is instead a **yellow triangle** with an exclamation mark on it.

**=>** You can refer to the "SVN Icon Overlay" documentation section at tortoise's website (http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html) for a good overview of the different overlays available.

**=>** Running the context menu action "Check for modifications" would've given you an instant status listing for each file/folder, showing what's really going on with them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the icons - they aren't updated regularly. I think the Windows has a cache for file/folder icons and after I-don't-know-what, the icon gets refreshed.

If you have nothing in your commit list, than it's all OK, the icon will be refreshed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Folder itself can have properties that are tracked by svn. One of such properties is svn:exernal that bindes external repository to current working copy (one repository within another).

In case where folder properties are conflicted you need to resolve file dir-prop-base inside .svn folder. When you manually resolve the file, like you would do for any other file, then you can actually mark it as resolved from conflict.