# SVN - cannot resolve conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have used SVN a lot but I haven't created my own SVN server from scratch before. I have created it, and all seems well. Except that I must have skipped some step before I made the dreadful mistake of changing a line of code in 1 of my files. Now, I cannot do a successful UPDATE from the server. I continuously get the error message shown in the screenshot:

[image]

There is 1 file conflicted in the "Scripts" folder. I have tried seemingly everything. I tried reverting it. Tried committing it (seems to always work!) I tried deleting it and re-updating from server. That worked. But when I try to update from the root, I always get the error shown below. This is Tortoise SVN.

I'm missing some simple step. Please help.

Comment: If all else fails you can checkout a fresh working copy.

Comment: How?? I tried that I think and it keeps complaining about that file. Please give exact steps, sorry I haven't used SVN in 2 years.

Comment: There is no possible way you can get that message on a brand new working copy. Right-click on an empty folder and choose "checkout...". You can get a new working copy where you can copy in your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer [TortoiseSVN reports conflict, but no conflict can be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414814/tortoisesvn-reports-conflict-but-no-conflict-can-be-found) to a similar question. The reason could be that you have changed the script folder on the server (lowercase to uppercase or vice versae), and your operating system (Windows) is not able to have both `Script` with uppercase and `script` with lowercase. A fresh checkout cannot have the effect you describe.